# How do I integrate wavesurfer js with a new Laravel project

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.7, wavesurfer.js

I am looking to implement the wavesurfer.js plugin in my laravel project but as I am a complete novice in javascript I have no idea where to even begin.

My audio files will be pulling from Amazon S3 which I have already set up but the wavesufer docs are not clear as to how to add this to my project. Can I input the code directly into my blade file or do I have to set this up with a Vue file for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as direct integration in your laravel project that way.

Here is the code that I have to update.

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@2.2.1/dist/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html, body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 200;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .full-height {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-center {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .position-ref {
            position: relative;
        }

        .top-right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 18px;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 84px;
        }

        .links > a {
            color: #636b6f;
            padding: 0 25px;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: .1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .m-b-md {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="top-right links">
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Wavesurfer laravel
            </div>

            <div class="links">
                <div id="waveform"></div>
                <button type="button" name="playbtn" onclick="wavesurfer.play()">Play</button>
                <button type="button" name="playbtn" onclick="wavesurfer.pause()">Pause</button>
                <span id="currentDuration">00:00</span> / <span id="duration"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var wavesurfer;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: "#waveform",
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple',
            responsive: true,
            // backend: 'MediaElement',
        });


        // Load the audio file here.
        wavesurfer.load('../storage/app/awwdw.mp3');    
        wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
            let time = wavesurfer.getDuration();
            $("#duration").text(formateTime(time));
        });
        wavesurfer.on('audioprocess', function () {
            let time = wavesurfer.getCurrentTime();
            $("#currentDuration").text(formateTime(time));

        });


        function formateTime(time) {
            var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60).toFixed(0);
            minutes = (minutes < 10)?"0"+minutes:minutes;
            var seconds = (time - minutes * 60).toFixed(0);
            seconds = (seconds < 10)?"0"+seconds:seconds;
            return minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds;
        }
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this will help you.